# Understanding proof of proposition $x \in F \to x \cdot 0 = 0$ where $F$ is a field.

Tags: field-theory, proof-explanation, finite-fields

**Axioms:**

- F1. *addition is commutaitve*: $x+y = y+x$, for all $x,y \in F$.
- F3. *existence of additive identity*: there is a unique element $0 \in F$ such that $x + 0 = x$, for all $x \in F$.
- F9. *distributivity*: $x(y+z)=xy+xz$, for all $x,y,z \in F$.

> *Proof*: By Axiom F3, $x0=x(0+0)$. By distributivity (Axiom F9), $x(0+0)=x0+x0$. By Axiom F3 again, $$0+x0=x0+x0,$$ and by Axiom F1 $$x0+0=x0+x0.$$
>   Hence, $0=x0$ by the preceding proposition.

How is the author instantiating the axioms in each justification ?

In the first justification, it seems he used Axiom F3 with $0$, reaching $$0=0+0$$ and then replacing in the equality $x0=x0$ but I do not see the steps clearly in the others.

EDIT:

When the author says "preceding proposition", he is referring to:

**Proposition.** If $F$ is a field and $x,y,z \in F$, then $$x+z=y+z \to x=y.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before we start, I want to re-state your claim as follows: if $F$ is a field, then
$$
t\in F \rightarrow t \cdot 0 = 0.
$$

All I've done is replace your "x" with "t". I've done so because $x$ is used in many of the axioms, and I don't want name-collisions to cause confusion.

> *Proof*: By Axiom F3, $x0=x(0+0)$.

Let's expand that. First, by axiom 3, instantiated with $x = 0$, we get 
$$
0 + 0 = 0.
$$
Then we apply the multiplication operation to both sides, multiplying by $t$. (I'm using here the fact that if $a = b$, then $ta = tb$, i.e., that multiplication is well-defined!). This gives us
$$
t\cdot (0+0) = t\cdot 0.
$$
(where $t \in F$ is the generic element of the field $F$ given in the hypotheses of this theorem).

> By distributivity (Axiom F9), $x(0+0)=x0+x0$.

In our version, this is the observation that the left hand side and be rewritten by Axiom F9, using $x = t, y = 0, z = 0$, to get
$$
t(0 + 0) = t \cdot 0 + t \cdot 0.
$$
So the whole equality becomes
$$
t \cdot 0 + t \cdot 0 = t \cdot 0.
$$

> By Axiom F3 again, $$0+x0=x0+x0,$$

The author has implicitly exchanged the two sides to write
$$
t \cdot 0 = t \cdot 0 + t \cdot 0 \tag{1}
$$
and then has applied axiom 3 to substitute for the left hand side, using $x = t \cdot 0$ in the axiom to conclude that 
$$
t \cdot 0 = 0 + t \cdot 0 \tag{2}
$$
and then replacing the left hand side of Equation 2 using Equation 1 to get
$$
0 + t \cdot 0 = t \cdot 0 + t \cdot 0. \tag{3}
$$

> and by Axiom F1 $$x0+0=x0+x0.$$

He's applying Axiom F1 to the left hand side of Equation 3, with $x = 0, y = t \cdot 0$, to get that 
$$
0 + t \cdot 0 = t \cdot 0 + 0,
$$
and then substituting this in Equation 3 to get
$$
t \cdot 0 + 0 = t \cdot 0 + t \cdot 0
$$

> Hence, $0=x0$ by the preceding proposition.

I'm assuming that the prior proposition says that if (in a field) we have
$$
a + b = a + c
$$
then $b = 0$. The author's applying this to $a = t\cdot 0, b = 0, c = t \cdot 0$.

Comment: Thank you so much, @John Hughes ! That's exactly what I was looking for. I forgot to add a reference to the previous proposition ($x+z=y+z \to x=y$). I'll update the post with it.

Comment: Do you know any book that explains this kind of proof with such detail ?

Comment: I do not know know of any such book, no. But once you've written out that level of detail for 3 or 4 proofs, you'll find that you can do so for the next 3 or 4 in your head, and then you'll stop doing it altogether (as I have for the last 50 years), but can still do it when necessary, as in this particular example. A math book in which everything was written out with this much detail would be very long, but prove very little (alas). Part of the goal of math is to condense like this to make getting to big results easier -- helping to see the forest, not just the trees.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice !

Answer (score 0):

By $F_{3}$ we have $x0 = x(0 + 0)$. Then, by $F_{9}$, we distribute and have $x(0 + 0) = x0 + x0$. Thus, together we have $x0 = x(0 + 0) = x0 + x0$. By $F_{3}$ we have $0 + x0  = x0$. This together with the previous yields $0 + x0  = x0 = x(0 + 0) = x0 + x0$. So we have $0 + x0 = x0 + x0$. Now, using $F_{1}$, we commute $0 + x0$ such that $0 + x0 = x0 + 0$. So we arrive at $x0 + 0 = x0 + x0$. By the previous proposition (left cancellation) we now have $0 = x0$.